# Convert floating raster to integer raster keeping cell size

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a float raster named **co.tif** with the following characteristics:

[image]

I am trying to convert this raster to polygon, so the [cell values are required to be integers](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012554).

When I try to convert pixel values to integers using the `Raster Calculator Tool`, the pixel size changes, my input pixels are not perfectly square, but I would like to keep the same pixel size when converting the values to integers.

The environment arguments that I have defined for the execution of the calculation are:

| argument | value |
| --- | --- |
| Output Coordinates | same as co.tif |
| Processing Extend | same as co.tif |
| Cell Size | same as co.tif |
| Cell Size Projection Method | Preserve resolution |
| Mask | co.tif |
| Snap Raster | co.tif |
| Compression | NONE |
| Tile Size | Width : same as co.tif ; Height : same as co.tif |

The result raster **co_int.tif**:

[image]

Pixel values are converted to integers, but the number of rows and the size of the pixel changes, taking as reference for X and Y the size of X of the **co.tif** only.

How do I generate an integer raster with the same cell size of the float_raster (co.tif) ?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.0.

Comment: if additional tools could be considered, perhaps gdal_polygonize.py may be of help.

Comment: The non-square pixels are the issue.

Comment: What created the raster? In all the years I have worked with esri software I have never seen a raster where the length of the X is different to the Y for cell size.

Comment: I do not think that you can keep the non-square pixels with raster calculator https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/analytics/what-happens-with-rectangular-raster-cells-in-spatial-analyst/. Use gdal_translate for conversion instead.